# Orbeon Form Runner iFrame Issue

Tags: html, tomcat, iframe, jboss, orbeon

I have published a couple of forms and can use them fine from the address they are on. I have another app on a different server and am calling the address in an iframe. The form itself loads but nothing is clickable. I can't change the wizards pages and none of the buttons at the bottom are clickable either.
What is wrong? It's just an iframe. Why is it having so much trouble?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's not working in an iFrame, but as an alternative you may want to look at [Form Runner ~ APIs ~ Server side Embedding](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-APIs-~-Server-side-Embedding).

Comment: after playing about with it, it seems that an iframe only works when running from the same server. ie. both are on localhost. If I pull the iframe from another server ip, nothing works. Very weird I say...

Comment: It could be an issue with cross site scripting. Your browser may be preventing the javascript from executing for security reasons.